# How to sort the order of track points?

Tags: qgis, point, sorting, order

I have a shapefile, which contains track points of a gpx file. Every track point has a number in its **"number"** field that tells the numeric name of the track the point belongs to. So points are clustered in a way. Unfortunately, there is no information about the order of the points (track segment) in a group. 
I have an unclear idea of using Python and a nested For-loop but my Python knowledge is super-limited. This VBA-ish method is the way I think it could work (I'm really sorry, I still have a lot to learn)

```
For n = 1 To 'max number of groups'
    fcount = 'number of features in a group' 
    For m = 1 To fcount
        track_seg = m           #field name where result goes       
    Next m
Next n
```

And this would be the preferred output in QGIS:

(Number one: start point; last number: end point).

[image]

Comment: The problem description is still unclear to me. Please confirm: 1. In your data, there is no column "track_seg" as shown in the screenshot? 2. You can only rely on the order of features in the attribute table? 3. You want to fill a "track_seg" column based on the order of features in the attribute table?

Comment: 1) There is a column "track_seg" but it's empty. In this picture, I filled it manually to show the desired output. 2) Yes 3) Yes, and using "number" field, which groups the points. So in group 1: start filling "track_seg" from 1 to n (where n=max number of points in a group; in this case to 5), in group 2: start filling from 1 to n again and so on..

Comment: @Skye Does the line in the attached image exist? I mean, do you have a point layer and a linestring layer, or a point layer only? If you have the line, it should be possible doing the task, otherwise I think it won't be impossible establishing which is the point to start from.

Comment: Both exist. Points are the track points of a gpx and lines are the tracks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, it might be useful in the future for others, too.

Not the most elegant way, but it works:

- I exported my table to a .csv file. Then, opened it in excel.
- Track_seg column is from B2 and the groups' column ("number") is from D2. I used this formula in cell B2 and copied down:

  =COUNTIF(D$2:D2,D2)
- After that I saved this table, returned to QGIS, created a Table Join using ID field and used Field Calculator to populate the appropriate column.

If somebody has a more elegant way of solving, please feel free to share your idea.